# SFTP transfer with keys

Tags: bash, debian, sftp

can somebody explain me how I can transfer files with SFTP over bash and with ssh keys instead of passwords? I use Debian 7 and openssh server.

Regards,
Akitoyo

Answer (score 2):

Create your keys with ssh-keygen, transfer your public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)  to the host with ssh-copy-id user@host.

Then simply sftp user@host from command line.

Comment: I did it that way, and it works when I do ssh user@host, but with sftp it stills ask me a password.

Comment: Check the value of the variable RSAAuthentication in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. If it is set no, either you change it to yes, or you generate an ssh dsa key with the command ssh-keygen -t dsa and copy it to your remote host as @user2815007 suggested.